# replace specific row value in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with 202 IDs. The last ID shows NA value rather than the specific value. I would like to know how to replace the NA to `ID202`. Here I am attaching my data:

```
ID = paste("ID", perHexStats$hexid, sep = "")
row.names(perHexStats) = ID
perHexStats = read.csv("perHexStats.csv", header = TRUE)
hspdf = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(hpg[ID],perHexStats, match.ID = TRUE)

"ID199" "ID200" "ID201" "IDNA"
```

You can see the last ID is NA. I need to replace it with `ID202`. How to do this is in `R`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. The code you provided doesn't really help us, because of course we can't read your data. Providing a sample of your actual dataset (by using, for example, `dput(head(df),10)`) would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
df$ID[df$ID=="IDNA"]<-"ID202"
```

If the cell actually is NA (rather than "IDNA"), the code would be:

```
df$ID[is.na(df$ID)]<-"ID202"
```

And, of course, if you know the row number is, say, 202, you can just do:

```
df$ID[202]<-"ID202"
```